# How to divide pandas dataframe in other blocks of data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do divide pandas dataframe in other blocks of data?

**Attention:** I don't want to do multiple queries to the database. I already have the query result in the desired size. What I need is to break the resulting dataframe into smaller dataframes.

I am start learn to work with pandas and try make a division of datas from a dataframe. I connect to **SQL Server** using **pyodbc** and get data with ***pandas.read_sql(...)***. The result is aproximately 5000 records. I need fragment the dataframe in blocks of 50 records without a loop (while, for, etc). I am convert the dataframe in dictionary and I am trying use compreension, but I don't have success:

```
[x for x in original_dataframe[:int(len(original_dataframe)/50)]
```

I need a result a blocks of other dicts or dataframes, e.g.:

```
block_01 = original_5000_records[:50]
block_02 = original_5000_records[50:100]
```

etc.

I yet do not understand weel, but I believe that is possible to use  pandas.shape() or pandas.iloc(), maybe there are the way. Someone can helpe me to make and compreend this? Thanks.

Comment: Use `chunksize` parameter in `pd.read_sql`

Comment: I don't want to do multiple queries to the database. I already have the query result in the desired size. What I need is to break the resulting dataframe into smaller dataframes.

Comment: Resolved using numpy method "array_split()"